# jQuery multiple form elements, checkbox id's and doing a calculation

Tags: jquery

Not really sure where to start with this one, so I am looking for a push in the right direction.

I have a form with multiple unique checkboxes and associated text inputs.  There is also a math value that will be applied to each of these upon checking the box.
Any help is appreciated in creating jQuery function to make this work:

example mockup:

[image]

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109179cb" /> 109179 - $4,390.30 <input type="text" name="applyto109179applyto" id="applyto109179applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($4,389.30)</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109246cb" /> 109246 - $4,231.76 <input type="text" name="applyto109246applyto" id="applyto109246applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($4,231.76)</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109314cb" /> 109314 - $3,934.40 <input type="text" name="applyto109314applyto" id="applyto109314applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($3,934.40)</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109381cb" /> 109381 - $4,240.52 <input type="text" name="applyto109381applyto" id="applyto109381applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($4,240.52)</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109447cb" /> 109447 - $4,261.30 <input type="text" name="applyto109447applyto" id="applyto109447applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($4,261.30)</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb109514cb" /> 109514 - $3,460.55 <input type="text" name="applyto109514applyto" id="applyto109514applyto" value="0" readonly="readonly" /> <em>($3,460.55)</em>
```

Comment: The picture really does not describe what you are trying to do. Could you put it into words?

Comment: Okay.  I have 10,000.00 and I want to apply this payment to one or more invoices shown.  As I select each invoicem if the amount is less than the 10,000.00 (or whever ther reamining balance is) it will either put in the full amount (as per the the first and third invoices in the pic), or what ever is left (as per the fifth invoice in the pic)

Comment: @MattBall Posted a reply.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#my_form input:checkbox[id^="cb"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $input = $this.next('input:text[id^="applyto"]');
    if($this.is(':checked')){
        // checkbox checked, apply your logic to $input
    } else{
        // checkbox un-checked, apply your logic to $input   
    }
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Ujx5n/)